# floated images in div with h4 heading not displaying properly

Tags: html, css

Am working on project in which i want to my images under a particular div tag to be floated to left next each other under an H4 tag describing a particular set of images when the H4 tag is outside the floated div.
I want to results to show something like this (with the .jpg representing the image files)

```
    Bar
    bar1.jpg    bar2.jpg    bar3.jpg

   Restaurant
   restaurant1.jpg   restaurant2.jpg    restaurant3.jpg

   Rooms
   room1.jpg    room2.jpg   room3.jpg
```

but yet am getting results that show something like this

```
    Bar
     bar1.jpg   bar2.jpg    bar3.jpg

    Restaurant
    restaurant1.jpg  restaurant2.jpg
    restaurant3.jpg

    Rooms
            room1.jpg   
    room2.jpg   
    room3.jpg
```

Here is a sample of my code with the HTML first

```
  <div id="services">

    <h4>Bar</h4>
    <div class="service">
        <img alt="Service Image" src="bar1.jpg">
        <img alt="Service Image" src="bar2.jpg">
        <img alt="Service Image" src="bar3.jpg">
    </div>

    <h4>Restaurant</h4>
    <div class="service">
        <img alt="Service Image" src="restaurant1.jpg">
        <img alt="Service Image" src="restaurant2.jpg">
        <img alt="Service Image" src="restaurant3.jpg">
    </div>

    <h4>Rooms</h4>
    <div class="service">
        <img alt="Service Image" src="room1.jpg">
        <img alt="Service Image" src="room2.jpg">
        <img alt="Service Image" src="room3.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>
```

and and this is my CSS

```
  div#services {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
  }

 div.service {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
 }
```

How can i solve this to display how want it to?

Comment: I'm not seeing the situation you describe based on the code you posted.

Comment: Why `float` on `div.service`? Just remove the float.

Comment: dude, learn html, css first

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

Its floating issue so add **clearfix** class on "class="service" div.

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: ".";
   display: block;
   clear: both;
   visibility: hidden;
   line-height: 0;
   height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
   display: inline-block;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

instead of put float de services class why not put to float the image and add a clearfix in the end of every services class like this.

```
div#services {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
div.service img {      
  margin: 0;
  margin-right:10px
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="service">
    <img alt="Service Image" src="http://placehold.it/200x250">
    <img alt="Service Image" src="http://placehold.it/200x250">
    <img alt="Service Image" src="http://placehold.it/200x250">

</div>
```

and go on...here is a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/XGLvf/

Comment: Why do you need to `float` the `img`s at all ??

Answer (score 0):

```
just add <div style="clear:both"></div> after service div is over at each time
<div id="services">
<h4>Bar</h4>
<div class="service">
<img alt="Service Image" src="bar1.jpg">
<img alt="Service Image" src="bar2.jpg">
<img alt="Service Image" src="bar3.jpg">
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<h4>Restaurant</h4>
<div class="service">
<img alt="Service Image" src="restaurant1.jpg">
<img alt="Service Image" src="restaurant2.jpg">
<img alt="Service Image" src="restaurant3.jpg">
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<h4>Rooms</h4>
<div class="service">
<img alt="Service Image" src="room1.jpg">
<img alt="Service Image" src="room2.jpg">
<img alt="Service Image" src="room3.jpg">
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the  tags expand onto multiple lines when their contents are too big. To override this, you need to add the following css to your div.service:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

and you need to remove the "float: left;".Your CSS file should now look like this:

```
div#services {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

div.service {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
}
```